# pass string from document properties drop down list in Spotfire to R script

Tags: r, spotfire

I have an R script working in Spotfire to plot contour maps for geochemical data as outlined below.

What i would like to do is to enable the user to change the z = SiO2 in the interp function from a drop down list of table headers to change the element e.g. z = Al2O3. I have created a drop down list of the table headers in a text area and created a document property as an a input into the script from this drop down list. What i cannot figure out is the syntax of how to how to pass this input parameter into the R script.

thanks for any ideas

```
    library(RinR)
    library (reshape2)
    library (akima)
    library (ggrepel)
    library (rgdal)



fld <- with(ECave, interp(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, z = SiO2 ))

df <- melt(fld$z, na.rm = TRUE)
names(df) <- c("x", "y", "element")
df$Lon <- fld$x[df$x]
df$Lat <- fld$y[df$y]

DenMapSq <- RGraph(print
                (

   ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, z = element)) +
         geom_tile(aes(fill = element)) +
     geom_point(aes ( x = Longitude, y = Latitude), data = ECave, inherit.aes = FALSE)+
     geom_text_repel(data = ECave,mapping=aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude,label=ECave$Well),
                     size=2.5, box.padding = unit(0.5, "lines"), inherit.aes = FALSE)+
     stat_contour() +
     ggtitle("element map") +
     xlab("Longitude") +
     ylab("Latitude") +
     scale_fill_continuous(name = "element (%)",
                           type = 'viridis') +
     theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 25, face = "bold"),
          legend.title = element_text(size = 15),
           axis.text = element_text(size = 15),
           axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20, vjust = -0.5),
           axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20, vjust = 0.2),
           legend.text = element_text(size = 10))


                                ),
                        packages=c('ggrepel','akima','reshape2','ggplot2'),data=c('fld','df','ECave')

            )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the document property as an input into the script correctly, you simply have to refer to it in the R script. For example, if I have an input document property as `input1`, I would write the following code in r to assign it to a variable I can use in r:
`inputDocProp <- input1`

In order to set this up properly, you define the input parameters on this screen (script screen):

[image]

And you set up the relationship between the parameter and the document property on this screen (parameters screen):

[image]

Assuming you do this correctly, you can read from the doc prop input field as stated above. The R script should run automatically every time that doc prop changes as well.